# Error in reactive({ : comparison (1) is possible only for atomic and list types

Tags: r, shiny, shinydashboard

The shiny app is linked to a function that finds the max or min of functions. I have radioButtons to choose between max and min. If max is chosen then the function is read in as the negative of the input function. I am getting the following error which I presume is connected to the radiobuttons: (if it is necessary I can upload the function)

```
Error in reactive({ : 
  comparison (1) is possible only for atomic and list types
```

UI:

```
library(shiny)
source("simulated_annealing.R")

ui <- fluidPage(
      titlePanel("Simulated Annealing App"),
             sidebarLayout(
             position = "left",
                 sidebarPanel("User input",
                              textInput("ObjectiveFun",
                                 h3("Objective Function"),
                                 value = "(x+2*y-7)^2+(2*x+y-5)^2"),
                              radioButtons("maxormin",
                                 h3("Goal"),
                                 choices=c("Minimise"=1, "Maximise"=2)),
                             ),
      mainPanel("System Outputs",
            textOutput("finalvalues")),
                         ),

               )
```

SERVER:

```
server <- function(input, output)
{
  #inputs
if(reactive({input$maxormin}) == 1)
  {
   Func <- input$ObjectiveFn
  }
else
  {
   Func <- paste(c("-(",ObjectiveFn,")"),sep="",collapse="",end="")
  }

  #call function.(Other input readings work)
value <- simannealing(Func,temp,I,A,alpha,nepochs,xlower,xupper,ylower,yupper)

  #paste 3-value vector returned by function
finalvalues <- paste("Final value is:", value[3],"and x value: ", value[1], "and y value: ", value[2])

  #print outputs
output$finalvalues <- renderText({
finalvalues
})  

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server
```

Comment: Inputs are reactive by default.  So `if (reactive({input$maxormin}) == 1)` is unnecessary.  And is the source of your error.  A `reactive` is a function, so it cannot possibly be equal to `1`.  (Though the `reactive`'s *value* might be.)  `if (input$maxormin == 1)` should be all you need.

Comment: @Limey Sorry I should have mentioned that I tried that but then I get the following error: Error in input$maxormin : 
  Can't access reactive value 'maxormin' outside of reactive consumer.
ℹ Do you need to wrap inside reactive() or observe()?

Comment: Ok.  In that case, put everything *inside* your server function but *outside* your `renderText` inside the `renderText`.  `renderXXXX` functions are reactive environments.